# Why is $\frac{\cos^2(z)-1}{z^2}$ at $z=0$ a removable singularity and not a simple pole?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I've been learning singularities in a complex analysis class, and I was given a problem to determine the kind of singularity for the function above. My first thought was to factorize the above numerator to get $\cos^2(z) - 1 = (\cos(z) - 1)(\cos(z) + 1)$. Therefore the numerator would have a single root, and the denominator would have a double root, meaning overall that $z=0$ would be a simple pole of the equation. According to my professor, this is wrong and the singularity is actually removable, and I should find the limiting value.

After finding this out, I made three solutions to find the limiting value. These being:

$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\cos^2(z)-1}{z^2}$ = $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{-\sin^2(z)}{z^2}$ =  $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{-\sin(z)}{z}$ * $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ = $-1$.

$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\cos^2(z)-1}{z^2}$ = $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{(1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}-...)^2-1}{z^2}$ = $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{(1-{z^2}+...)-1}{z^2}$ = $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{-z^2+...}{z^2}$ = $-1$ via Taylor Expansions.

$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\cos^2(z)-1}{z^2}$ = $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{-2\sin(z)\cos(z)}{2z}$ = $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{2\sin^2(z)-2\cos^2(z)}{2}$ = $-1$ via L'Hopital's Rule.

What I don't understand is what made my original solution incorrect in the first place, does my factorization not work in $\mathbb{C}$? Or is what I attempted to do not a valid way of determining singularities. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: “Therefore the numerator would have a single root ...” – No, $(\cos(z)-1)$ has a *double* zero at the origin.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I managed to miss something like that! I forgot that only works with polynomials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\cos(z) -1$ has a zero of order $2$ at $0$. $$\cos(z) -1=-\frac{z^{2}}{2!}+\frac{z^{4}}{4!}-....$$